# Errorcode? Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXCi386_GPFLT)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to programming and I'm getting this error

Not sure what to do, but the app hangs

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD5Ny.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `@` before your "Chocolate Cake" string.  You can't put c strings into `NSArray`

Answer (score 0):

I think u are missing the alloc. You have to allocate memory.

in your .h :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * recipes;
```

in your .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.reciepe =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test",@"test2",@"test3",nil];
}
```

Dont forget the nil at the end of the arry.

This work fine for me.

Hope this help.

Comment: Actually I thought so as well, but this is not correct. I will work with @dan's answer

Comment: @mad_mask, you are wrong. The NSArray class function "arrayWithObjects" is a helper method or "class factory" method that allocates an array for you, fills it with the objects you pass in, and returns it. This is a common pattern in Cocoa/Cocoa touch.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code using code tags rather than a screen-shot. Quote the whole error you get, and indicate which line number it's on.

Dan told you what was wrong with your code (a missing "@" on one of your parameters.)

Make sure you look at all warnings you get when you compile your program. You almost certainly got a warning that you were passing a parameter of the wrong type. Those warnings are really, really important. When you get a warning, stop everything and figure out why.

Apple added new syntax for creating objects ("object literal" syntax, it's called.)

You could write your code more simply like this:

```
recipes = @[@"test", @"test2", @"test3"];
```

The effect is exactly the same as the code

```
recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"test", @"test2", @"test3", nil];
```

But the new form is easier to type, and easier to read once you get used to it.

The official (somewhat hard to read for a beginner) documentation is on the Clang website: [**Objective-C Literals**](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

[**This article from The Big Nerd Ranch site**](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/objective-c-literals-part-1/) is a more readable explanation of the new syntax (it also includes a link to the same page on the Clang site)

If you do a google search on "Objective-C object literal syntax" You'll find a bunch of other articles as well.